# Is there a way to disable autocompletion in all applications running in a windows 7 machine?

Tags: windows-7, autocomplete

I need autocomplete disabled for all applications (windows forms mainly) that run in a windows 7 machine.

I have found instructions on how to disable IE autocomplete , Explorer and run command autocomplete, but no indication on how to do it globally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunatelly, this is not possible due to the fact that every application handles autocompletion on its own regardless of system settings :-(

Answer (score 1):

All the applications are programmed for autoecompletion on its own. So you can't control it through system settings.